# I want to convert byte data in Java to C

Tags: java, c

I want to convert byte data in Java to byte in C.

`a` is `int` and `b` is `byte`; and I have code in Java like this:

```
b[0x00]  = (byte) ((a>> 8) & 0xFF);
```

how can I convert above statement in C?

Comment: Remove `(byte)`. Done.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Your Java code won't compile if `b` is a `byte` and not a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is virtually equivalent in C as both the >> and & operators are identical in both languages.

```
int a=2200;
unsigned char b=((a>>8) & 0xFF);
```

Comment: I want to print the signed value of b actually. But its showing me decimal value.

Comment: sign value? unusual but okay - how are you printing it?

Comment: My (byte)((a>>8) & 0xFF) : this value is coming as -2 in java; But in c am getting it as 254, which is int value of ((a>>8) & 0xFF); This conversion of byte(254) is: -2; so i want -2 in C as well.

Comment: one more question: I have byte array with some values in it.
byte a[]={49,51,53,46}, 
String s = new String(a);
How can i convert this in C?